# NativeScript - unit tests throwing errors

Tags: angular, unit-testing, nativescript

I'm writing an app with NativeScript 6+ and Angular 8+. I'm trying to write some unit tests for my services with karma and jasmine. My unit tests are throwing errors.

How can I write my unit tests properly? I read and followed the directions on this web page but it still doesn't work: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tooling/testing/testing

The error that I'm getting happens in other services as well not just this one.

karma.config.js

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'src/tests/setup.ts',
  'src/tests/**/*.spec.ts'
],
```

test

```
import {
  nsTestBedAfterEach,
  nsTestBedBeforeEach,
  nsTestBedRender
} from 'nativescript-angular/testing';

import { HttpInterceptorService } from '../app/core/interceptors/http-interceptor-service';

describe('HttpInterceptorService', () => {

  beforeEach(nsTestBedBeforeEach([HttpInterceptorService]));
  afterEach(nsTestBedAfterEach(false));

  it('should be created', () => {
  });

  it('should have its functions defined', () => {
  });

});
```

Error:

```
NativeScript / 13.3 (13.3; iPad): Executed 15 of 17 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.018 secs)
NativeScript / 13.3 (13.3; iPad)  undefined at line undefined FAILED
    An error was thrown in afterAll
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.location.origin') (line 108)
        at <Jasmine>
    at file:///app/vendor.js:157139:46
        at <Jasmine>
    at file:///app/vendor.js:157341:57
        at <Jasmine>
    at file:///app/bundle.js:1389:28
        at <Jasmine>
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.location.origin') (line 108)
        at <Jasmine>
    at file:///app/vendor.js:157139:46
        at <Jasmine>
    at file:///app/vendor.js:157341:57
        at <Jasmine>
    at file:///app/bundle.js:1389:28
        at <Jasmine>
NativeScript / 13.3 (13.3; iPad): Executed 16 of 17 (1 FAILED) (0.084 secs / 0.018 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 15 SUCCESS
CONSOLE LOG file:///node_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/app/main-view-model.js:132:0: NSUTR: this.error: An error was thrown in afterAll
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.location.origin') (line 108)
at <Jasmine>
at file:///node_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.jasmine.js:1445:0
at <Jasmine>
at file:///node_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:188:0
at <Jasmine>
at file:///src/main.ts:11:16
at <Jasmine>
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.location.origin') (line 108)
at <Jasmine>
at file:///node_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.jasmine.js:1445:0
at <Jasmine>
at file:///node_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:188:0
at <Jasmine>
at file:///src/main.ts:11:16
at <Jasmine>
CONSOLE LOG file:///node_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/app/main-view-model.js:120:0: NSUTR: completed test run.
CONSOLE LOG file:///node_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/app/main-view-model.js:120:0: NSUTR: completed test run.
CONSOLE LOG file:///node_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/app/main-view-model.js:124:0: NSUTR: completeAck
CONSOLE LOG file:///node_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner/app/main-view-model.js:124:0: NSUTR: completeAck
NativeScript / 13.3 (13.3; iPad) ERROR
```

This is a code snippet from my http interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private httpLoaderService: HttpLoaderService,
        private authentication: AuthenticationService,
        private ssoAuthentication: SsoAuthenticationService,
        private endpointHelper: EndpointHelperService,
        private router: RouterExtensions
    ) {}

    public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
```

It's in a module called 'core'

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from 'nativescript-angular/common';
import { HttpInterceptorService } from './interceptors/http-interceptor-service';
import { HttpLoaderService } from './shared/http-loader.service';
import { NativeScriptHttpClientModule } from 'nativescript-angular/http-client';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    NativeScriptCommonModule,
    NativeScriptHttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [HttpInterceptorService, HttpLoaderService],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

Comment: Can you show what you have in HttpInterceptorService? Are you loading NativeScriptHttpClientModule?

Comment: The error happens in other services as well.